# Insert stylesheet into WordPress header?

Tags: headers, css

I just want to add one extra line (a third-party font stylesheet) to the header of my blog. I have a child theme set up, but at the moment it only has a custom stylesheet, `style.css`.

Very simply, how can I do this?

All the answers I can find seem to suggest that I create multiple long and complicated files that replicate a lot of parent theme code. Surely there must be a simple way?

If I create a new `header.php` with just one line (the extra stylesheet), as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25196999/194000), that file overwrites all of `<head>`.

If I add a simple `functions.php` file [like this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25197032/194000), it just inserts raw code into the page.

Is there any way I can just insert one line into the header without having to replicate all the header PHP code? Surely it can't be this hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply enqueue your stylesheet using the get_stylesheet_uri()

```
function my_scripts() {
    // enqueue style
    wp_enqueue_style('name-of-my-script', 'https://cloud.typography.com/6718632/6718632/css/fonts.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks. What should I call the file in which I do this?

Comment: It's an external stylesheet: `https://cloud.typography.com/6718632/6718632/css/fonts.css`. Should I replace `/style-sheet.css` in the above with this URL?

Comment: And is `name-of-my-script` significant in some way, or can I leave that string as it is?

Comment: I think from Googling - this file ought to be called `functions.php` and it ought to have enclosing PHP tags - is that right?

Comment: this would be placed in your functions.php file,  name-of-my-script can be changed to anything.  It is used to ensure the style is not loaded twice

Comment: You are correct in your last question.  Wrap it in php tags.  I updated the answer to show you how to include your external stylesheet